# I have a seemingly very hard wiring problem to solve

Tags: electrical, electronic-control-module, renault, throttle, clio

Further to my last [question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/73370/why-does-my-obd2-scanner-not-reset-the-errors-as-well-as-a-mechanics) :

I have a Renault Clio 1.2 2010 that keeps coming up with a [P0638](http://www.dtcsearch.com/P0638/?from=Torque) (Throttle Actuator Control Range/Performance) error (according the the OBD2 device I have).

One thing I noticed this summer is that on a warm day, the error will not occur. I can reset the error codes using an OBD tool and the error lights will not flash up until the evening. In the winter, they come on pretty much straight away.

It has been to the mechanics several times, but they have been unable to locate the problem. They did try replacing the throttle unit, but this didn't fix the problem. It seems they reset the error and then can't get the error to occur again so they can't track down the problem. Indeed the error doesn't come up again for a few days after the car has been with them. (When I reset the error codes with my tool, the error is back within an hour max (apart from on warm sunny days)).

The car has had this problem for 3 years now, and apart from not driving as fast hasn't caused any other problems. Due to a change in law in the UK, it is now going to fail its MOT on 21 Jan, so I am going to have to get it fixed.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue and where I could go from here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my OBD2 scanner not reset the errors as well as a mechanics?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/73370/why-does-my-obd2-scanner-not-reset-the-errors-as-well-as-a-mechanics)

Comment: Take it to a (good) dealer - they have detailed experience and factory sourced information that local mechanics don’t have.

Comment: @SolarMike Thats me asking that question. :-)